# I am not able to create new db in my mongodb localhost

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongoose

here is my js file with all the code.

```
var Product = require('../models/product');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('localhost:27017/shopping');
var products = [
new Product({
    imagePath: 'https://d28dwf34zswvrl.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/125-fall-in-love.png',
    title: '',
    discription: 'Awesome Game!!',
    price: 10
}),
new Product({
    imagePath: 'http://www.accounting-coach.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/product.jpg',
    title: '',
    discription: 'Amet sint tempor enim cupidatat.',
    price: 20
}),
new Product({
    imagePath: 'https://www.gs1us.org/portals/0/Images/02_UPCs_Barcodes_and_Prefixes/02-1-2_Choose_Product_GTIN_or_Location_GLN_Identification/02-1-2-module-data-hub-product-video@1x.png',
    title: '',
    discription: 'Amet sint tempor enim cupidatat.Amet sint tempor enim cupidatat.Amet sint tempor enim cupidatat.',
    price: 30
}),
new Product({
    imagePath: 'https://www.acesled.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Prod02.png',
    title: '',
    discription: 'Amet sint tempor enim cupidatat.Amet sint tempor enim cupidatat.Amet sint tempor enim cupidatat.',
    price: 40
}), new Product({
    imagePath: '',
    title: '',
    discription: 'Amet sint tempor enim cupidatat.',
    price: 50
})
];
var done = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
products[i].save(function(err, result) {
    done++;
    if (done === products.length) {
        exit();
    }
});
}
 function exit() {
mongoose.disconnect();
}
```

I have all my schema in models folder which is imported very first.
I have made an array to save all the data one by one `by using save method of mongoose`
I am using for loop to save all my data which is there in the array. Everything goes fine but when I run show DBS in my cmd. There is no database with name shopping. 
Can anyone help me out? How do I save data in my localhost of MongoDB??

Comment: solved!! there was a spelling mistake in the discription field so i used..

Comment: products[i].save(function(err, result) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        done++;
        if (done === products.length) {
            console.log('saved');
            exit();
        }

Comment: You should also learn to use [`.create()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create) or better [`.insertMany()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany) which does everything you are doing without the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Neil Lunn had mentioned, you can use `Mongoose.insertMany` to insert multiple documents. Change your products array to an object and pass it into the Product.insertMany, like what I've done below:

```js
var products = [{
    imagePath: 'https://d28dwf34zswvrl.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/125-fall-in-love.png',
    title: '',
    discription: 'Awesome Game!!',
    price: 10
},
{
    imagePath: 'http://www.accounting-coach.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/product.jpg',
    title: '',
    discription: 'Amet sint tempor enim cupidatat.',
    price: 20
},
{
    imagePath: 'https://www.gs1us.org/portals/0/Images/02_UPCs_Barcodes_and_Prefixes/02-1-2_Choose_Product_GTIN_or_Location_GLN_Identification/02-1-2-module-data-hub-product-video@1x.png',
    title: '',
    discription: 'Amet sint tempor enim cupidatat.Amet sint tempor enim cupidatat.Amet sint tempor enim cupidatat.',
    price: 30
},
{
    imagePath: 'https://www.acesled.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Prod02.png',
    title: '',
    discription: 'Amet sint tempor enim cupidatat.Amet sint tempor enim cupidatat.Amet sint tempor enim cupidatat.',
    price: 40
},
{
    imagePath: '',
    title: '',
    discription: 'Amet sint tempor enim cupidatat.',
    price: 50
}];

Product.insertMany(products, function(error, docs) {
  if (error)// do something with error
  
  // do something with docs, etc
  if (docs.length === products.length) exit();
});
```